# jQuery - Select an element by ID not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I'm trying to select an element and then add / remove a class. I have achieved this plenty of times with other elements, however for this one it doesn't want to work.

My html is as follows:

```
<div>
 <a class="login-headerText" id="hypLogin" style="padding-right:5px; float:left" >Login</a>
 <h4 class="login-headerText" style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:5px; float:left">/</h4>
 <a class="login-headerText"  id="hypCreateAccount">Create Account</a>
</div>
```

The div is wrapped inside another div. (id=modal)

I want to select "hypLogin" then add a class to it on click. It works if i do this in the onClick event, however it wont work in a seperate script. (The script is referenced and works as it is used for other elements)

This is my jQuery

```
$('#hypLogin').click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('login-headerText').addClass('login-headerText-Unselected');
});
```

Tried debugging it and it's not getting hit at all.

Probably something really simple.

Comment: Did you wrap it in `$(function() {...}`

Comment: but the id = hypLogin, the class = login-headerText

Comment: Yes, I saw. You also had addClass("hypLogin")  in the onclick

Comment: yea but thats commented out (<%-- --%), ill remove that from the question

Comment: the whole script is wrapped in $(function() yes

Comment: Right click on your page and view-source to see if id(hypLogin) has been modified by asp.net

Comment: Are you sure the id is not used twice in your HTML?

Comment: I can't replicate this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/V8r2G/

Comment: Nope it's not been modified

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yep the id is definitely unique

Comment: +1 for the invalid element. Does the fiddle provided above work for you?

Comment: Yes the fiddle works for me, so it must be something deeper...

Comment: @Satpal nope it's not dynamically added

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @MrUpsidown yes: http://jsfiddle.net/nick9732/5Lek7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. you must do it on:

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
   });
   ```
2. Does these elements printed dynamically?
3. try to use:

   ```
   $('#hypLogin').on('click', function () {
   });
   ```
4. try to put your code on modal open event.

Comment: Thank you, but I've tried those and still cant get it to work.

Comment: Strange.. i have jQuery referenced as a script at the bottom of my html doc  <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Actually yes i do - Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: The weird thing is, the other funtions in the same script work

Comment: Try to console log inside the click function And maybe before the $('hypLogin').on and after.

Comment: it outputs to console inside the login click, (which works) then doesnt do anything inside the hypLogin click

Comment: Oh dear very silly mistake, when i said i had tried wrapping it in the 'login' click. I did it before the e.preventDefault();, it needed to be after!

Comment: Did you try do do that with on('click' instead of .click?

Comment: What is this "custombox" jquery plugin? It open the modal?

Comment: Yes thats the open model script. .4 in your answer worked after i placed / the click function after e.preventDefault(); Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

[Here is working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/uNNnG/)

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hypLogin').click(function () {

        $(this).removeClass('login-headerText').addClass('login-headerText-Unselected');
    });
});
```